# In PySpark how to parse an embedded JSON

Tags: pyspark

I am new to PySpark.

I have a JSON file which has below schema

```
df = spark.read.json(input_file)

df.printSchema()

 |-- UrlsInfo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- displayUrl: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: long (nullable = true)
```

I want a new result dataframe which should have only two columns **type** and **UrlsInfo.element.DisplayUrl**

This is my try code, which doesn't give the expected output

```
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("the_table")  
  resultDF = spark.sql("SELECT type, UrlsInfo.element.DisplayUrl FROM the_table")
  resultDF.show()
```

I want resultDF to be something like this:

```
Type | DisplayUrl
----- ------------
2    | http://example.com
```

This is related [JSON file parsing in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543903/json-file-parsing-in-pyspark), but doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your schema, `UrlsInfo` is an array type, not a struct. The "element" schema item thus refers not to a named property (you're trying to access it by `.element`) but to an array element (which responds to an index like `[0]`).

I've reproduced your schema by hand:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(UrlsInfo=[Row(displayUri="http://example.com", type="narf", url="poit")], Type=2)])
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- Type: long (nullable = true)
 |-- UrlsInfo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- displayUri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

and I'm able to produce a table like what you seem to be looking for by using an index:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
resultDF = spark.sql("SELECT type, UrlsInfo[0].DisplayUri FROM temp")
resultDF.show()

+----+----------------------+
|type|UrlsInfo[0].DisplayUri|
+----+----------------------+
|   2|    http://example.com|
+----+----------------------+
```

However, this only gives the first element (if any) of `UrlsInfo` in the second column.

**EDIT:** I'd forgotten about [the `EXPLODE` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#explode), which you can use here to treat the `UrlsInfo` elements like a set of rows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(UrlsInfo=[Row(displayUri="http://example.com", type="narf", url="poit"), Row(displayUri="http://another-example.com", type="narf", url="poit")], Type=2)])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
resultDF = spark.sql("SELECT type, EXPLODE(UrlsInfo.displayUri) AS displayUri FROM temp")
resultDF.show()

+----+--------------------+
|type|          displayUri|
+----+--------------------+
|   2|  http://example.com|
|   2|http://another-ex...|
+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to Concat all elements in displayUrl into a String on the same row?

Comment: If you don't use `EXPLODE`, the `UrlsInfo.displayUri` column stays in array format. You can `CAST(UrlsInfo.displayUri AS string)` if you want, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that